# create field55, set token or pan

Tags: e-commerce, nfc, payment, emv

I create Field55 to make emv transaction from NFC-terminal, all work fine but it's need to set by what method user make pay: token (Apple/Google Pay) or by physical card (pan). I know how to get it when read payment but, but can not find which tag in filed55 responsible for this information. If anyone know - please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand what you are doing. Card emulation on tokenized wallet transactions in face to face interface produces exactly the same data as for any other card. If you are trying to produce face to face transactions from ecommerce tokens - it's not possible as this will generate in best case a 3DS cryptogram, not EMV data (with an irrelevant exception).
Can you maybe explain better what you are trying to achieve?